# Maintaining order between input and output in Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to trim some sequences in a file, and each string of sequence has a corresponding string of characters that describes the sequence quality. This is an example (one of many thousands in the file):

```
@HS2:447:C2DFYACXX:4:2309:9964:54984 1:N:0:GCCAAT
TGCATNGCAGGCTGCTTCCTTTCTAGATCAGCTAGCAGCTGCAGGAAGGCATATTTTGG
+
BBBBF#0<FFFFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIF
```

I need to trim the lines starting with TGCA... and BBBB..., and output the shorter strings along with the other two lines lines (to remain un-modified) to a new file, in the same order. I have found how to trim the strings, but I can't figure how to keep these four lines together in the new output file.

This is what I have written so far:

```
import gzip
new_seqs=[]
with gzip.open('ALJG001B_index6_GCCAAT_L004_R1_004.fastq.gz', 'r') as file:
    n=0
    file_content = file.readlines()
    for line in file_content:
        n+=1
        if n % 4 == 0:
            new_seqs.append(line)
```

And of course, it produces a list of only the last line (of every 4 lines):

```
['BBBBF#0<FFFFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIF\n', ...]
```

And this is the code I have written to trim the sequences:

```
if len(line) > 50 and not line.startswith('@'):
    print line[:-9]
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself. Comments don't preserve indentation.

Comment: Hopefully it's better now. Sorry.

Comment: lists are ordered so as long as you append the lines in order, you can iterate through them in the same order and write to an output file.

Comment: But each element in the list doesn't contain all the items that need to be written to the output file. This is my difficulty, having these 4 lines together, but only editing two of the lines.

Comment: @Jared Good enough to change my vote. BTW get rid of `file_content = file.readlines()` and just change that loop to `for line in file:`. It does the exact same thing in a far more memory-efficient way.

Comment: you are iterating through each line as you go along so put your `if` statement for editing inside your for loop and append the line after that if statement, regardless of whether it was edited or not

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trimming reads from a fastq file, use the fasta formatting guidelines to your advantage. Just append lines starting with '@' or '+' without trimming and trim lines the sequence and quality lines.

```
 for line in file_content:
    if line[:1] == '@' or line[:1] == '+':
       new_seqs.append(line)
    else :
       new_seqs.append(line[:-9])
```

Comment: So simple, yet so effective! Thanks so much for the help!